# Automated Re-fetching not working - RTK-Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Using RTK-Query
Help.

I'm fetching only following users post on HomePage
Its showing all following users post,
but when following user creates new post, its not Auto Re-Fetching,
I have to reload the page manually then its rendering.

**Issue:** I have only one route for getting following users post data **'/api/followingUsersPost'**.
For Auto Re-Fetching it needs mutation and thats the issue here,
And in my case mutation is not in my hand, following user will update the data / dont know when. so yeah thats why i need auto re-fectch. and thats the issue How should rtk-query know that a new post has been added

```
// Store.js

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import AuthSlice from './AuthSlice';
import { profileApi } from './rtk';
import { followingUsersPostApi } from './FollowingUsersPost';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: AuthSlice.reducer,
    [profileApi.reducerPath]: profileApi.reducer,
    [followingUsersPostApi.reducerPath]: followingUsersPostApi.reducer,
  },

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
      profileApi.middleware,
      followingUsersPostApi.middleware
    ),
});

export default store;
```

```
// FollowingUsersPostApi.js

import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const followingUsersPostApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'followingUsersPostApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api' }),
  tagTypes: ['Post'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    //
    followingUsersPost: builder.query({
      query: () => `/followingUsersPost`,
      invalidatesTags: ['Post'],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useFollowingUsersPostQuery } = followingUsersPostApi;
```

```
// HomePage.jsx
import { useFollowingUsersPostQuery } from '../../Store/FollowingUsersPost';

const HomePage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFollowingUsersPostQuery();
}
```

I checked docs but there is **providesTags** and **invalidatesTags**
but i have only one route for getting followers post,
so i have use **invalidatesTags**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How should rtk-query know that a new post has been added?
I don't see a mutation in which you add a new post. Please see [mutations documentations](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations), and after that see how [cache](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior) works in rtk-query.

**Polling**
If you can't handle the mutation, I suppose the interval updates your only way.
[Read more about polling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling)

```
const state = useFollowingUsersPostQuery(undefined, { pollingInterval: 3000 });
```

Comment: Thanks for response.
I have read docs, it needs a mutation to re-fetch data. but in my case mutation is not in my hand, following user will update the data dont when. so yeah thats why i need auto re-fectch. and thats the issue How should rtk-query know that a new post has been added

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure that's what you want, but that's the only idea.

Comment: Thanks, polling working, but it is costly operation for my backend, until i dont use cache for my backend too.

Update your ans with polling code and remove addNewPost. ill upvote

Comment: ok, I'll remove the mutation handling solution, because that's not the case when it's needed.

Comment: @folov55205 You might need a secondary endpoint to "ping" which gives you a very minimal bit of information, like the timestamp of the latest post in the feed.  That way you do not need to return the entire data on every polling interval.